# Пунктуация в сложном предложении с союзом «и»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп, и

**На работе вы найдете парик и вам ответят на звонок.**

Если оба простых предложения внутри сложного имеют общее обстоятельство, ставится ли перед **и** запятая?

Answer (score 1):

Это зависит от того, является ли второе предложение следствием первого. В этом примере такого нет, так что запятая не нужна. И то и другое — две вещи, которые просходят на работе, именно потому, что для них характерно случиться в этих обстоятельствах.

Answer (score 1):

Вот что говорится в [правиле](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133).

Перед союзами *и, да* (в значении *и*), *или, либо* запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены каким-либо общим элементом.
Общим может быть второстепенный член предложения:
***В селе*** не переводилась лихорадка и была топкая грязь (Ч.); ***В это время*** тягуче скрипнула дверь сеновала и наружу просунулась голова деда Щукаря (Ш.).

Запятая перед **и** в вашем (согласитесь, немного странном) предложении не нужна.